# Why isn't my viewModel working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, knockout.js

I'm struggling with this 3 days and can't get my mind around why the first viewModel is working but second isn't , it even doesn't allow me console.log() anything.

My view Models and ko bindings:

```
// KO View Models
var indexViewModel = {
    item: ko.observableArray([]),
    cat: ko.observableArray([]),
    loadcontent: function () {
        alert("inside index function");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/all',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var getArray = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    getArray[index] = item;
                });
                indexViewModel.item(getArray);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/category/all',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var getArray = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    getArray[index] = item;
                });
                indexViewModel.cat(getArray);
            }
        });
    }
};
var dataReal = null;
var itemViewModel = {
    item: ko.observableArray([]),
    loadcontent: function (getID) {
        alert(getID);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var getArray = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    getArray[index] = item;
                });
                itemViewModel.item(getArray);
                dataReal = data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case 404:
                        alert('File not found');
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        alert('Server error');
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        alert('Request aborted');
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Unknown error ' + status);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

var mainViewModel = {
    indexPage: indexViewModel,
    itemPage: itemViewModel
};

ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);
```

My working HTML:

```
<div id="index-content" data-bind="init: mainViewModel.indexPage.loadcontent(), with: mainViewModel.indexPage">
    <div class="item-list" data-bind="foreach: item">
        <div class="item-container clearfix">
            <div class="item-content clearfix">
                <div class="title" data-bind="text: Title">
                </div>
                <div class="left-side clearfix">
                    <div class="item-image" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(content/u/'+Image+')' }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-descr">
                        <div class="body" data-bind="text: Body">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-more-details">
                            Vairāk...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the HTML witch even ignores my console.log() calls:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    int id = ViewBag.id;
}

<div id="item-details-content">
    <input type="hidden" id="item-id" value="@id" data-bind=""/>
    <div class="item-list" data-bind="init: itemPage.loadcontent(@id), with: itemPage.item">
        <div class="item-container clearfix" data-bind="init: console.log($root)">
            <div class="item-content clearfix">
                <div class="title" data-bind="text: Title">
                </div>
                <div class="left-side clearfix">
                    <div class="item-image" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(content/u/'+Image+')' }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-descr">
                        <div class="body" data-bind="text: Body">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-more-details">
                            Vairāk...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Where is syntax errors?
3. How can I get console.log() working there?
4. Maybe there is an alternative to my problem, maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept of KO.js?

### Conclusions

1. I know there is data inside `mainViewModel.itemPage.loadcontent($.ajax(data))` because alert() shows it, but it doesn't pass the value to `item`!
2. I'm a newbie, total newbie, and if I thought I'am somewhat a decent programmer now I think I am total dumb ass and I am starting to hate KO.js, but I need it very badly!
3. **NOTE:** You can see in debug section that index page works just fine.

### DEBUG PLACE

---

Here is published [web application](http://dacesimane.lv:8080)

---

And here is [single item page](http://dacesimane.lv:8080/item/details/36)

### THANK YOU

**Thanks everyone for helping me, I was so frustrated that I even didn't see any more the obvious, thanks again! Cheers!**

Comment: What is the output of `data` on the AJAX calls? How is it structured?

Comment: @rcdmk can you give me example how I can print out `data` structure?

Comment: you can print it opening directly the endpoint  on the browser (eg: "http://localhost:1234/api/item/all'). This will open the JSON response and you will be able to see the data i you open it in your editor of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) At first glance, I noticed your HTML bindings are referring to mainViewModel. For example:

```
data-bind="init: mainViewModel.itemPage.loadcontent(@id), with: mainViewModel.itemPage.item
```

should likely be

```
data-bind="init: itemPage.loadcontent(@id), with: itemPage.item
```

You are already bound to mainViewModel

2) For debugging, use this to see what you are bound to in the view.

```
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON(yourViewModelGoesHere, null, 2)"></pre>
```

3) The data being returned is not an array, though you are treating it as such.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var getArray = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            getArray[index] = item;
        });
        itemViewModel.item(getArray);
        dataReal = data;
    },
```

If you create a sample at http://jsfiddle.net we can help you more.

Comment: Is it a special plugin? Because my chrome console shows `Object #<Object> has no method 'debugInfo'`

Comment: Here is the site I just published for you http://dacesimane.lv:8080 and single item page http://dacesimane.lv:8080/item/details/36 , jsfidlle will be to hard to make, and it won't represent the true nature anyways.

Comment: sorry, fixed the debug info. try that.

Comment: I updated my answer. The data coming back for the second view model is not an array, tho you treat it as such.

Comment: Ok I made the variable as `ko.observable()` but now when it should show `dacesimane.lv:8080/content/u/img.jpg` it try's to show `dacesimane.lv:8080/item/details/content/u/img.jpg` how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Within the `data-bind` elements, you are referring to your model relative the the object you specified in the `applyBindings()` function. In your case, you called `applyBindings(mainViewModel)`, so in the bindings themselves, you refer to its properties, not to `mainViewModel` itself.
2. In your non-working HTML, `<div class="item-container clearfix" data-bind="console.log($root)">` seems suspicious. What kind of binding is this? It doesn't specify any particular property to bind.
3. Use your browser's developer tools (Firebug in Firefox, Developer Tools in Chrome/IE...) to see the syntax errors. If there are problems with bindings, you will see them there.

Comment: 1. I cleared these errors 2. fixed this(but it still won't work) 3. It really shows that `Title` isn't defined.

Comment: Then it looks like that the data your receive via Ajax do not contain the `Title` property. Can you show us the data?

Comment: Go to http://dacesimane.lv:8080/item/details/36 and in console check variable `dataReal` it should show the structure of `object`